# How to exploit this C program to call a certain function?

Tags: c

The goal is to call the function `foo` in the following program:

```
struct object {
    unsigned char buf[36];
    void (*fp)();
};

void baz(struct object * obj, unsigned int num) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        unsigned int x;
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (x == 0) break;
        obj->buf[i] = x & 0x000000ff;
    }
}

void foo() { // target
}

void bar() {
}

int main() {
    setvbuf(stdin,  NULL, _IONBF, 0); 
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); 
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    struct object * obj = malloc(sizeof(struct object));
    memset(obj->buf, 0, 36);
    obj->fp = &bar;

    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (num > 36) {
        num = 0;
    } else {
        baz(obj, num);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("%d. \t", i + 1);
        for (int j = 0; j < obj->buf[i]; j++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        puts("");
    }

    obj->fp();
    free(obj);
}
```

My thoughts were to modify `fp` in `obj` (which is called at the end) such that it points to `foo` instead of `bar`. By entering a negative number for `num` such that it becomes a large positive number when casted to `unsigned int` in `baz`, this should allow the modification of `fp` by overflowing `buf` in `obj`. However, this would require the address of `foo` which changes every time the program is run.

I would appreciate any ideas or hints to solve this problem.

EDIT: This is a homework question.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Yes, so it would be good if I can get some hints instead of the full answer.

Comment: Alright, then please [edit] your question to clarify that it is for homework. Did your professor mention anything about ASLR? (E.g. you should disable it, your're not allowed to disable it, etc.)

Comment: Edited. I didn't hear anything about ASLR. I'm supposed to connect to a server (which executes this program) and provide input for `scanf`.

Comment: Then it might be that that server is configured "correctly" already. Have you tried checking how `foo()` and `bar()` are placed relatively to each other?

Comment: @MechMK1 I tested locally and found that `&foo + 0x37 = &bar` on every run (although the addresses themselves change).

Comment: See which call instruction are used for call fp (relative E8 or absolute FF)

Comment: @MechMK1 ASLR wouldn't randomize locally defined functions, it would be PIE that does this, which can't be turned off unless you recompile the executable.

Comment: @multithr3at3d You're probably right. i don't know too much about binary exploitation

Comment: If it is not compiled for debugging, there is no way - the function is unused and gets optimized away.